# Como trabalhar e alternar múltiplas View Controllers via código?

Tags: swift, xcode

Sem utilizar um botão para alternar entre as views, que tudo ocorra via código.

Já tenho a parte que valida as credenciais do usuário, mas quando estão corretas não sei como fazer para exibir a segunda View que contém um `UIWebView`.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde, você tem duas telas correto? e você quer que depois que o usuário valide vá para a sua outra View certo? Vá na sua View da Credencial, Segure e Arraste a Bolinha amarela com o Control e coloque Show,

faça um seguimento da tela com um Identifier , coloque o nome que quiser,

Depois do codigo que o usuario se loga ou faz as credenciais só coloque abaixo do codigo :

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("NomeDoSeguimento", sender: self)
```

Um exemplo Simples é o Login do facebook, após ele logar, é só colocar abaixo o perfomrSegueWithIdentifier, que ele vai para a view que voce colocou o Segue..

não esqueça de criar o seguimento!

[image: Identifier]

que no meu caso é showLogin! Com esse codigo você consegue mandar o usuario para a View que quiser contanto que coloque o nome certo no Identifier!

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, consegui resolver.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

Primeiramente você precisa dar um id as suas View Controller destino

Isso pode ser feito desta forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora você pode usar este id para chegar até a View Controller

Você deve usar este código no arquivo Swift de sua View origem para ir a View destino quando quiser alternar para esta View Controller.

## Swift

```
var viewController: UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View2") //View 2 é o id que vc especificou na sua View Controller
         self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

Desta forma ele vai para a View destino.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Se não quiser utilizar o performSegue, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
let newView = SecondViewController()
self.presentViewController(newView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Esse método não requer que você manipule o storyboard.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método `delegate` do `UITextField`:

```
textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

Para verificar os caracteres digitados no campo ou campos, são iguais a os dados cadastrados por um usuário, caso sejam, ir para a segunda View ou outra especifica.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta.